# How to remove components created with Angular-CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am working on angular2 for my new project, newly with this technology. I have set-up my project with angular CLI (Reference site https://github.com/angular/angular-cli).
I have created 4 components using command `ng generate component my-new-component`
For testing purpose, created one component app-testing, need to remove that component from my project. Else need to rename for that component. I have tried several like. `ng destroy component app-testing` but showing error **The destroy command is not supported by Angular-CLI.**, Please help me with solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: not supported yet. manually remove folder

Comment: This happens all the time. The first result by my search engine bought me here. The original SO linked as duplicate was in 3rd place.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I had the same problems and it seems that they removed the destroy command from the CLI and you need to do it manually by deleting or renaming the according folders/files and imports, which is really a laborious task.

> https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/900
>   https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1788

Comment: would be useful to see them adding in an automated command again. Whole point of the CLI is to make your life easier (rather than blocking you from using commands).

Comment: see my answer... there are better ways to "undo" now.

Comment: better is to use --dry-run for example ng g c componentName --dry-run command it will show you what component is going to create and at what location and if you are ok then run the same command without --dry-run

Answer (score 10):

You can delete any component by removing all its lines from app.module.ts . Its working fine for me.

Comment: see my answer... there are better ways to "undo" now.

Answer (score 2):

version control is your friend here, do a `diff` or equivalent and you should see what's been added/modified.

In fact, removing the component folder might not be enough; with Angular-CLI v1.0, the command `ng generate component my-new-component` also edits your `app.module.ts` file by adding the respective `import` line and the component to the `providers` array.

Answer (score 2):

You should remove your component manually, that is...

```
[name].component.ts
[name].component.html  // if you've used templateUrl in your component
[name].component.spec.ts  // if you've created test file
[name].component.[css or scss]  // if you've used styleUrls in your component
```

If you have all that files in a folder, delete the folder directly.

Then you need to go to the module which use that component and delete

import { [component_name] } from ...

and the component on the declarations array

That's all.
Hope that helps

Comment: Yes, you're right. For now, there isn't better way to remove the component beside manual removing.

Comment: @Dimang Chou see my answer... there are better ways to "undo" now.

Comment: Don't look at @FlavorScape 's answer...

Answer (score 1):

**No** As of now you can't do this by any command. You've to remove **Manually** from `app.module.ts` and `app.routing.module.ts` if you're using *Angular 5*

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, couldn't find a right solution so I have manually deleted the component folder and then updated the app.module.ts file (removed the references to the deleted component) and it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I tried ng remove component Comp_Name also ng distroy component but it is not yet supported by angular so the best option for now is to manually remove it from the folder structure.

Answer (score -1):

This is the NPM [known](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5641) Issue for windows that NPM is pretty much unusable under Windows. This is of course related to the path size limitations.

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5641

My main concern here is that there are no mention of these issues when installing node or npm via the website. Not being able to install prime packages makes npm fundamentally unusable for windows.

Comment: Nothing to do with the OP question.

Answer (score -4):

Try to uninstall angular and then reinstall

npm uninstall --save @angular/(then whatever component you want deleted)

after that, a box with babyblue color border will appear with suggestion to update and install angular back up.

Answer (score -8):

There's the `--dry-run` flag which will allow you to preview the changes, and/or you can use the [Angular Console App](https://angularconsole.com) to generate the cli flags for you, using their easy GUI. It auto-previews everything before you commit to it.

Comment: have you read the question? `How to remove components...`